# Parametrice UFT with function

Tags: hp-uft

I´m newbie in UFT. I´m creating test for a form in a web page. I need parametrice a field but I don´t see any way to finish it, because the field is a Spanish official document of identity and is a eitht number concatenate with a letter.

I have a vbscript function to calculate that string, but i don´t know how to insert in the field. I´ve tried with enviroment, but i don´t see how operate.

Function is below.

```
Function numNie(ByVal dni)
    Dim tabla,pos
    tabla = Array("T","R","W","A","G","M","Y","F","P","D","X","B","N","J","Z","S","Q","V","H","L","C","K","E")
    pos = dni mod 23
    sacaLetra = tabla(pos)
    numNie=dni & sacaLetra
End Function
```

Comment: Hi , Your question is not clear. Give some example for dni  & numNie(output that you want)

Comment: For example, if number is 78248723, the letter is D, and nie (or dni) is 78248723D. I can parametrice it with selenium ide, where i can put that number as a variable and i can type in field properly. But i don´t know how make it in UFT.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to Set the value of the web edit field to be the return value of your function:

```
Browser("yourWebsite").Page("yourWebPage").WebEdit("yourWebField").set numNie(dni)
```

This is of course assuming that your function is defined (either within the script or within a function library that is associated with your test), and that the web site, web page and field all exist with the object repository associated with the test.

Comment: The script, in expert mode is:

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to type something(the string return value of your function) into a field on a web page...  I think.  If that's what you're trying to do, then here's how I would do that.

First, I'm assuming you have the web page up in a browser already.  I hope you've gotten that far already.  (I'll make up an example browser and page name...)  Also, I'm assuming that the field you want to enter this data into is a WebEdit control, and you are just trying to type the value into it.

If all this is correct, then the method you want is .Set to get UFT to type a value into the webedit.  The code in your action would look like:

```
DocumentNumber = numNie(dni) 'call your function to get the document number

Browser("Website").Page("Page to enter data").WebEdit("name of field").Set DocumentNumber ' type the document number into the webpage
```

or just

```
Browser("Website").Page("Page to enter data").WebEdit("name of field").set numNie(dni)
```

probably followed by

```
Browser("Website").Page("Page to enter data").WebButton("Submit").click
```

Note that "Website", "Page to enter data", "name of field", and "Submit" are the names of browser, page, webedit and webbutton objects from the Object Repository that your action can see.  Obviously, those should be the names of your test objects, but they could also be descriptions instead.

Comment: Thanks, but problem is i can´t parametrize it. I´d like when i run the test, in that field, execute function and types the result in the field

Comment: Perhaps you could describe what is going wrong when you try to parameterize it.  What I described in one line should do it...  "Browser("Website").Page("Page to enter data").WebEdit("name of field").set numNie(dni)"

Comment: Thanks very much.

Your solution has worked in my test. However i see every time i run the test doesn´t change random number. What is i do wrong???

Comment: I didn't see anything in your question about a random number...   however, if you need to generate a random number, you could use the RND() function with a seed that has entropy.  Better yet, you could instead use the RandomNumber object built in...  Example: The following example generates a random number between 0 and 100. x=RandomNumber (0,100)

Comment: the random numbe is in function, Now is below (sorry, i didn´t paste)

Comment: Function numNie
 dni = int(rnd*30000000) + 10000000
    Dim tabla,pos
    tabla = Array("T","R","W","A","G","M","Y","F","P","D","X","B","N","J","Z","S","Q","V","H","L","C","K","E")
    pos = dni mod 23
    sacaLetra = tabla(pos)
    numNie = dni & sacaLetra
End Function

Comment: all times I run the test function return same number, and i need that number would be different (it´s national number of identity)

Comment: That's a completely new question.   But, it's simple, so here:  Add "Randomize" on a line before dni = int(rnd*30000000) + 10000000.

Comment: @user942324 Then please accept the answer that was most useful so the question disappears from the unanswered questions list.

Answer (score -1):

You can parameterize using Datatable(i think this is best way)

Create a Excel file in some local folder(ex: `C:\Tests\InputData\Test1.xls`)

Fill sheet values like below

```
Ex:

IterationID  | dniValue    
 1           | 21   
 2           | 15
```

then in the script use below script

```
Datatable.import(ExcelsheetPath) 'C:\Tests\InputData\Test1.xls
For i = 1 to Datatable.GetSheet(1).GetRowCount
Datatable.setcurrentrow(i)
 dni= Datatable.value("dniValue", 1) 'get dnivalue
 objwebpage.WebEdit("name of field").set numNie(dni)
Next
```

---

or if you want random `dni` values then use `random` function like below

```
Function random(v1,v2)
 Randomize
 random=(Int((v2 - v1 + 1)* Rnd + v1))
End Function
```

then call the function to generate randow `dni` value

```
dni =random(1,23)
objwebpage.WebEdit("name of field").set numNie(dni)
```

Comment: A version that uses the integer square root is missing. Seriously: 1. Why the `random` suggestion? The question does not say a word about it. 2. What is the `Randomize` call good for? It should be called only once to seed the random generator (or at least once would suffice). 3. The only thing adressing OP´s question is the `objwebpage.WebEdit("name of field").set numNie(dni)` line, which is already the key statement of an older answer. -1